# To show the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ are same

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I want to show that the cardinality of the countable infinite product of the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to find a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ or vice versa but not getting a suitable bijection. Please help.